# subtracting two unsigned 32-bit integers and assign to 64-bit signed integer

Tags: c, syntax, integer-arithmetic

The goal is to get (-1) as the final result.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{

    uint32_t us32Var1, us32Var2;
    int32_t s32Var1;
    int64_t s64Var1;

    us32Var1 = 0;
    us32Var2 = 1;
    printf("(1) us32Var1 = %u(0x%08x), us32Var2 = %u(0x%08x)\n", us32Var1, us32Var1, us32Var2, us32Var2);

    s32Var1 = us32Var1 - us32Var2; //0xffffffff (-1)
    printf("(2) s32Var1 = us32Var1 - us32Var2, s32Var1 = %d(0x%08x)\n", s32Var1, s32Var1);

    s64Var1 = us32Var1 - us32Var2;  //0x00000000ffffffff  (expect it's -1, but the result > 0)
    printf("(3) s64Var1 = us32Var1 - us32Var2, s64Var1 = %ld(0x%016lx)\n", s64Var1, s64Var1);

    s64Var1 = (int64_t)(us32Var1 - us32Var2);  //0x00000000ffffffff  (expect it's -1, but the result > 0)
    printf("(4) s64Var1 = (int64_t)(us32Var1 - us32Var2), s64Var1 = %ld(0x%016lx)\n", s64Var1, s64Var1);

    s64Var1 = (int64_t)us32Var1 - us32Var2;  //0xffffffffffffffff  (-1)
    printf("(5) s64Var1 = (int64_t)us32Var1 - us32Var2, s64Var1 = %ld(0x%016lx)\n", s64Var1, s64Var1);

    us32Var1 = -1; //us32Var1 = 0xffffffff, UINT32_MAX
    s64Var1 = (int64_t)us32Var1; //0x00000000ffffffff  (expect it's -1, but the result > 0)
    printf("(6) s64Var1 = (int64_t)us32Var1, s64Var1 = %ld(0x%016lx)\n", s64Var1, s64Var1);

    s64Var1 = (int32_t)us32Var1; //0xffffffffffffffff  (-1 !)
    printf("(7) s64Var1 = (int32_t)us32Var1, s64Var1 = %ld(0x%016lx)\n", s64Var1, s64Var1);
    return 0;
}
```

For the above program (each line is numbered), can someone explain

- Why (2) works as expected, but not for (3)? what's the arithmetic or micro-steps for ALU?
- What's the difference between (4) and (5)
- Why does (7) work while (6) fails

Answer (score 2):

(2) works, but probably not the way you think. `us32Var1-us32Var1` will yield the unsigned value `0xFFFFFFFFU` (modulo arithmetic) and the assignment to `s32Var1` converts it to a signed 32 bit value, thus `-1`. In (3) the assignment also converts it, but now to 64 bit signed value and that is big enough to contain the `0xFFFFFFFFU`, so it stays positive. The difference between (4) and (5) is that in (4) the subtraction takes place in 32 bit and then is converted to 64 bit. In (5) one of the operands is converted first to 64 bit, thus making the subtraction 64 bit and therefore the other operand is implicitly converted to 64 bit too. (6) is similar to (2), the signed value `-1` in 32 bits is converted to an unsigned 32 bits in the assignment to `us32Var1` and thus the result is `0xFFFFFFFFU` this fits easily in `s64Var1`, so it stays positive. In (7) `0xFFFFFFFFU` is first converted to a signed 32 bit and thus is `-1`, which then is assigned to signed 64 bit and thus results in `-1`.

I hope this helps.

So in answer to your questions below. In (3) the subtraction is still done in 32 bits unsigned, so the result is `0xFFFFFFFFU` because `-1` can not be represented in unsigned. This 32 bit unsigned result is converted to signed 64 bit, which can exactly represent `0xFFFFFFFFU`, so that is the result.

For (7) the assignment indeed does the sign-extension, because the right hand side is 32 bit and negative. Note that the variable `us32Var1` contains (of course) a positive value, but it is converted to a 32 bit signed value that can not represent `0xFFFFFFFFU` and thus it is turned into `-1` by the cast.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, but I still have some questions.
First, what are the detailed steps to (3)? the two unsigned 32-bit are first cast to signed 32-bit to perform subtraction, stored as unsigned 32-bit, and then assigned to 64-bit signed integer?
As for (4) and (6), the (int64_t) casting on the uint32_t doesn't extend the sign of it, i.e., 0xffffffff to 0xffffffffffffffff? then how does (7) work? the assignment actually extend the sign from 32-bit to 64-bit?

Answer (score 2):

- *Why (2) works as expected, but not for (3)? what's the arithmetic or micro-steps for ALU?*

Well, it works the way *I* would expect. The unsigned<sub>32</sub> result is computed, then the unsigned value is converted to signed, and so naturally it is zero-extended.

- *What's the difference between (4) and (5)?*

(4) is the same as the one I described above, and (5) ends up computing 0LL - 1LL which, as it happens, makes ~0LL. What other result could it possibly make?  It might be helpful to note that, inside the machine, there isn't much difference between signed and unsigned numbers. The exact same ALU is used for signed and unsigned operations. With a few exceptions, the **signed** vs **unsigned** distinction is one made when interpreting the results and when deciding whether or not to sign extend, but not one made while actually executing arithmetic ALU operations.

- *Why does (7) work while (6) fails?*

I'm not sure I would say (6) *failed*, exactly. You converted an unsigned value to a signed one, so naturally it zero-extended it. In (7) you converted a signed<sub>32</sub> value to 64-bits, so naturally it was sign-extended.

Comment: I think my misunderstanding so far is on the sign-extension, i.e., when it's done, how it's done. From your description, it seems the sign-extension depends on the data type of the original data, but not on the type of the assigned target, e.g., (3). Even the explicit casting as (4) doesn't affect the decision of sign-extension.

Comment: You will need to dig up a statement of the C type conversion rules somewhere. A copy of the ISO standard is best. But it's expensive, so, briefly: arguments are promoted through the type hierarchy (small to large, signed to unsigned) when combined with an operator. And, `=` is *just another operator.*  Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I am more clear about it now. Will check the standard also.